# Return value of UsersModel::myFunc() must be of the type string, object returned

Tags: php, mysql

I get this "Fatal error" when I call this function:

```js
public function myFunc(int $id) : string
    {
        $statement = self::$db->prepare("Some query WHERE id = ?");
        $statement->bind_param("i", $id);
        $statement->execute();
        $result = $statement->get_result();
        return $result;
    }
```

Can you give me advice where can I read for this types of errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it like that (if you use MYSQLi):

```
    #SELECT field1 FROM xyz where id = ?
    $result = $statement->get_result();
    $data = $result->fetch_row();
    return $data['field1']?$data['field1']:'';
```

Note on `Fatal Error` the funtion has an ReturnTypeHint `string` so you have to return a string. 
Read here: http://php.net/manual/en/class.typeerror.php and here: http://php.net/manual/de/functions.returning-values.php